# Django - Update field values in extended user model after a request is performed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, signals, django-users

My project is a social networking site that can send requests to friends and make friends.
I have extended django's existing user model using oneToone field .

So far i've been able to do the above said thing but when ever a user accepts the request , Both the user who sent request and also the user accepted it must increment a value in their extended user model which stores the value of their friends count . 
I'm facing difficulties trying to solve this .
I've also used signals but it doesn't work .

Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Friends(models.Model):
"""Model for saving relationship of user and friends"""
     request_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='current_user')
     friend_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_friend')
     created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Friends"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.friend_id)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    friends_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/',blank=True,null=True)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.user.username,)
```

signals.py:

```
    @receiver(post_save,sender=Friends)
    def update_friends_count(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        if created:
            user_profile = Profile(user = instance.request_id)
            user_profile.friends_count=F('friends_count')+1
            user_profile.save()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!! Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Can you correct the indentations and comments?

Comment: Is it Okay !!!! Do you have any idea to solve this??? @JerinPeterGeorge

Comment: I think you have to implement `M2M` relationship rather than `FK` relationship

Comment: How would that solve my problem ....I want to have a count of friends not the relationship...because everything works fine if the method in signals.py is cleared out

Comment: You defined it for each instance, but you need that for whole `Profile` table

Comment: I did not understand.
Can you show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were initializing a new instance of Profile every time a friend is made. Instead you can use get_or_create to generate a profile or retrieve the one associated with that id. Next, you want to update both users so fetch the other update the counts and save.

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Friends)
def update_friends_count(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        user_profile, profile_created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = instance.request_id)
        user_profile.friends_count=F('friends_count')+1
        user_profile.save()

        friend_profile, profile_created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = instance.friend_id)
        friend_profile.friends_count=F('friends_count')+1
        friend_profile.save()
```

With Q filter and update

```
Profile.objects.filter(
    Q(user=instance.request_id) | 
    Q(user=instance.friend_id)
).update(
    friends_count=F('friends_count')+1
)
```

This last query uses the `django.db.models Q` object to make an SQL `OR` statement to retrieve the two profile instances; that of the requested and the requester: the `update` call acts on the query and updates all instances in the list

Comment: you're welcome! I added another solution that accomplishes it in one query

Comment: the second query uses the Q object to create an `OR` SQL query and the update call will update all the instances that are returned by the query.